# NextAuth SignIn function for Oauth is not returning response

Tags: next.js, next-auth

```
const oAuthSignIn = (type: string) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        signIn(type, { redirect: false })
            .then((callback) => {
                console.log(callback); //undefined
                if (callback?.error) {
                    window.alert("Invalid credentials");
                }

                if (callback?.ok) {
                    router.push("/initial-setup");
                }
            })
            .catch(() => window.alert("something went wrong"))
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
};
```

I want to get some response inorder to redired to my route. But as it is returning undefined .then is not called.